# How to populate google maps info boxes from database?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I'm trying to populate a google map with several geo-points and associated info windows, all stored in a database. My code compiles without errors, but the infowindow content isn't working right. I'm working in c# and javascript.

This code fills each info window with the string "some words." I can also get it to work by replacing "some words" with @row.Lat and/or @row.Lng and populate the info window with the correct numbers from the database. However, when I type in @row.Description (the name of the row when the content I want is), then the map doesn't load, but I don't get any error message. If I put @row.randomStuff (a nonexistent row) then I get an error, so I know that @row.Description is being read but not understood.

```
    @{
    var db = Database.Open("ClownDB");
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Point";

foreach (var row in db.Query(query)) {
    <text>
    var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(@row.Lat, @row.Lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerPosition, 
        map: ClownMap, 
        clickable:true});
    marker.content = "some words";

    var InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function({
            InfoWindow.setContent(this.content);
            InfoWindow.open(ClownMap, this);
            });
            </text>
        }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you need '@' in front of 'row' since you are already in a code block.

Comment: Thanks, but taking out the @s made new errors :(

Comment: Try surrounding @row.Description with quote marks.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: Great! I have submitted it as an official answer.  Please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
marker.content = "some words";
```

with:

```
marker.content = "@row.Description";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `@`
before your `foreach (var row in db.Query(query)) {` code as specified in this [.NET tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_database.asp). It should be:

`@foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){`

Other ways of passing .NET data to javascript are mentioned [here](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/02/05/passing-net-server-side-data-to-javascript) .